# Snapshot the axes in app designer for Report Generator - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

Based on this question [Append image to PDF report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61635207/append-image-to-pdf-report) , I was wondering is it possible to snapshot the axes in app designer in order to save them in PDF report?

I tried the code below but I get an error

Error:

```
Undefined function 'getSnapshotImage' for input arguments of type 'matlab.ui.control.UIAxes'.
```

Code:

```
function ButtonPushed(app, event)

    import mlreportgen.dom.*;
    import mlreportgen.report.*

    folder = 'E:/';
    file = 'shapes2.png'
    fullFileName = fullfile(folder, file);

    I= imread(fullFileName); 
    level = graythresh(I);
    BW = imbinarize(I,level);
    imshow( BW ,'Parent', app.UIAxes) 


    filter = {'*.pdf'};
    [file, pathPDF] = uiputfile([folder,filter{1}])


    if file ~= 0 
        d = Document('myPDF','pdf');
        d.OutputPath = [pathPDF,file];
        figure = app.UIAxes;
        snap = Image(getSnapshotImage(app.UIAxes,d));
        img1 = Image(fullFileName); 
        img1.Style = [img1.Style {ScaleToFit}];
        close(d);     
    end 
end
```

Comment: Do we actually have the function `getSnapshotImage`?

Answer (score 1):

The error mentions that you are using the incorrect input type. When this type of error is displayed, you should check the function signature to check what it expects.

I suggest you familiarize yourself with the Mathworks documentation and learn to use the help browser directly from MATLAB (right click on function name, then *Help on selection*).

You will find that the function `getSnapshotImage` accepts, as a first argument, a `mlreportgen.report.Figure` object, and *not* a `matlab.ui.control.UIAxes` object.

Reference: https://www.mathworks.com/help/rptgen/ug/mlreportgen.report.figure.getsnapshotimage.html#d120e37424